# Excel VBA to copy a chart from multiple sheets, then combine them in a single graph on a separate sheet

Tags: excel, vba, graph

I am writing some VBA code that will copy a chart from each worksheet in my workbook then paste a **combined** chart on a new worksheet.

Manually, I know I can copy each chart and then paste on top of the previous chart where each dataset will be available. However, this is painfully manual. I wish to create a VBA macro to do this instead.

Currently, my code copy and pastes the chart from each sheet into a new sheet, but they are still separate charts. I need some guidance.

```
Sub copyGraphs()
Dim OutSht As Worksheet
Dim Chart As ChartObject
Dim PlaceInRange As Range

Set OutputSheet = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("PostProcess")
Set PlaceInRange = OutputSheet.Range("A1:J21")

'Loop charts
For Each Sheet In Worksheets
    Sheet.Activate
    
    If Range("A4") <> "" Then
        'Copy/paste charts
        ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Activate
        ActiveChart.ChartArea.Copy
        Sheet.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Copy
        OutputSheet.Paste PlaceInRange
    End If
Next Sheet
End Sub
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Edit:

I ended up having to run a loop for each graph. It still requires one to manually ensure 'Chart 1', 'Chart x' are in the main sheet named PostProcess in my code. It is rather brute force to me, but it works.

```
Sub copyGraphs()
Dim OutSht As Worksheet
Dim Chart As ChartObject
Dim PlaceInRange As Range
Dim chartInput As Chart
Dim chartOutput As Chart

Set Outputsheet = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("PostProcess") '<~~ Output sheet


'Loop charts for efficiency
For Each Sheet In Worksheets
    Sheet.Activate
    
    If Range("A4") <> "" Then
        'Copy/paste charts
        ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Activate
        ActiveChart.ChartArea.Copy
        
        Sheets("PostProcess").Select
        ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Activate
        ActiveChart.Paste


    End If
Next Sheet
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you have to paste your input charts directly into the combined chart, and not into a specified range.  You have to use something like:

```
Dim chartInput As Chart
Dim chartOutput As Chart
Set chartInput = Sheet1.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Chart
Set chartOutput = Sheet1.ChartObjects("Combined chart").Chart

chartInput.ChartArea.Copy
chartOutput.Paste
```

Comment: I still had an error with this code, unfortunately, I did not spend too much time trying to debug the error. I ended up writing a loop for each graph type I wanted to copy from a sheet and then paste to the main sheet. I had to make sure the main sheet had 'Chart 1', 'Chart 2', and 'Chart 3' for it to work correctly.